# Wifi frequently drops but it says it's connected in the top right corner. [Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS]

Tags: wireless, asus, disconnect

I have been getting issues trying to get wifi working on my PC. I can browse the internet for about 5 minutes then the internet drops and I have to manually disconnect then reconnect to get my connection back. I'm confused because it says I'm connected to my network but really, I'm not. If it helps, I'm using a ASUS USB-N13 b1 revision wireless adapter with RTL8192cu drivers and an ActionTec V1000H router. All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This has happened to me a few times.

It usually is a problem with the router, not your wi-fi.

1. Unplug the router from the power outlet and wait 20 seconds before
   plugging in again.
2. Reboot your PC also just to be sure.

### Another problem can be an IP conflict

So you have to `reserve a dedicated internal IP address` for your computer.

1. Access your router using the internal IP (usually 192.168.0.1 if
   using a DLink device but it may vary)
2. Use your user and password (usually user: `admin` and password: `admin` or blank)
3. Search for `Network settings` and wherever you notice a table of
   MAC addresses and IP's, you should find a button to "reserve"
   IP's.
4. Reserve the IPs of devices you recognize as yours.

`NOTE: Instructions are different depending on the make and model of your router.`

And that's it.

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help. Just out of curiosity, which one did? modem reboot or ip conflict fix?

Comment: This did not help me. (And I'm not terribly surprised, as only my Ubuntu laptop experiences this behavior, whereas the router never drops any other device I own.)

Comment: @JellicleCat, you can alos try `$ rfkill block all` and then `$ rfkill unblock all`, that will refresh your wifi interfase